# Geopy Geocoders returns the correct results in one way, but not another

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopy

I'm trying to find the address of some universities. If I do this, everything is totally fine.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='ryan-data')

import pandas as pd

df = ['Rutgers University, New Jersey',
        'Bucknell University, Pennsylvania',
        'Colgate University, New York',
        'Cornell University, New York',
        'Syracuse University, New York']

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.columns=['school']
df.head()

df['location'] = df['school'].apply(lambda x: geolocator.geocode(x))
df.head()
```

When I do that, everything comes out fine. However, if I read the EXACT SAME ADDRESSES from a CSV file, like this.

```
try:
     df['location'] = df['school'].apply(lambda x: geolocator.geocode(x))
except:
     df['location'] = 'not found'
    
df.head()
```

The exact same code always throws an error. I don't want to type out every single address. I just want to read from a CSV and get the results. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with this.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter

#Creating an instance of Nominatim Class
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my_request")
 
#applying the rate limiter wrapper
geocode = RateLimiter(geolocator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=1)
 
# applying the method to pandas DataFrame
try:
    df['Location'] = df['Address'].apply(geocode)
    df['Lat'] = df['Location'].apply(lambda x: x.latitude if x else None)
    df['Lon'] = df['Location'].apply(lambda x: x.longitude if x else None)
except:
    df['Location'] = 'none found'
```